# inherit C# from JSAPI

Tags: c#, c++, firebreath

I have created an application which inherit the C++ Dll in .Net application with the help of the [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/12/08/inheriting-from-a-native-c-class-in-c.aspx) which used the Concept of Virtual Table.I  was trying to find out the possibility for inhering C++ Dll in .Net. Above Link is very helpful for me.
Now, I want to inherit my C# class from JSAPI of Firebreath framework which is the supporting framework of Native C++. I am using the Dumpbin.exe to verify which functions are exported in my .Net application.
Please let me know if any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to directly do what you want to do; however, you could possibly create something that extends JSAPI that can then wrap a managed object, though, using the reflection APIs to implement methods like HasMethod, HasProperty, GetProperty, SetProperty, and Invoke.  Go look at NPObjectAPI in the firebreath source as kinda an example of what I mean.  FireBreath has several such objects that make things that don't normally conform to JSAPI act like JSAPI objects.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.Could you please suggest me what i want to create that extends JSAPI that can then wrap the managed object?I am going to implement  C++ class library that can be used as wrapper which will include the plugin.h,pluginApi.h files so that i can easily access my Firebreath Functions.Then is it the correct way to call firebreath functions in the C#?

Comment: You would create a C++ object that extends JSAPI.  You would then put reference and such to the managed object inside that object.  You would then add code to proxy calls between the two.

Comment: There is no "correct way to call firebreath functions in the c#". There is whatever way that works that you create.

Comment: Many Thanks .I have done the same as you mentioned.Now It works well.